# How to find src attributes in video?

Tags: node.js

I'm using axios and cheerio and I want to scrape the `src` in video tag.

If I just scrape img tag like `$('img')`, it shows me all attributes about that tags.

but If I scrape video tag like `$('video')`, it just shows `{}` (empty object..)

How can I scrape src in video tags?

```
axios.get(url)
    .then(res => {
        const html = res.data.;
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);

        const text = $('#playerArea video');
        console.log(text);  // never show me any attribute..

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
const text = $("#playerArea").attr("src");
console.log(text);  // never show me any attribute..
```

Comment: It didnt work.. just show me 'Undefined'. It's really awkward because work great when I did it same webpage and same code with img tags.

Comment: Get the id of the video, and do the same logic.
If the id of the video is 'myVideo' so:
const text = $("#myVideo").attr("src");

Comment: Can you add the source of the html you get from cheerio.load(html);

Comment: https://tv.naver.com/v/1376712    << I was going to do that on this site (Lang is korean).

Comment: This site have no video tag. It renders the video with images stream: <div role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" class="rmc_dummy_container"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAJCAYAAAA7KqwyAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3wccBTIrwFRftwAAAB1pVFh0Q29tbWVudAAAAAAAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBkLmUHAAAAD0lEQVQoz2NgGAWjgAoAAAJJAAEMrHXpAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" alt=""></div>

Comment: I think I need more study about it :D.. I really appreciate your comments!

Comment: try  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Answer (score 0):

getAttribute() worked for me.

```
const videoElem = elem.querySelector('.video-class').getAttribute('attribute-name');
```

or your example..

```
const text = div.querySelector('.rmc_dummy_container').getAttribute('src');
```

would output the (base64 encoded) src (from Or Assayag's comment)